# Hats running around!

Tags: discussion, bug, specific-user, winter-bash

Very quick question before hats are put back into the box: in http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/leaderboard , the second user in math.SE, jimmyk4542's hat always hides on top of the page for me, as in screenshot. I noticed this few days back, thought it is some page load error, but it happened again today!
[image]

Does it happen only for me? Why is it happening? Also, his profile pic is missing for me in math.SE!

P.S. confused if I should add "bug" tag, will do if someone confirms its not happening  only for me alone!

**Edit:** In his profile, when I switched to Activity tab and back to profile tab, this happens:
[image]

If I scroll and reload his userpage, hat is put on top wherever I scrolled down to! I'm on Firefox 43/UbuntuMint 14.04 (If my memory is correct I noticed it first in Windows)

Comment: It's where it ought to be for me. At least, it was just a moment ago when I looked. Does it remain that way if you reload the page?

Comment: @DanielFischer, on leaderboard, it stays on top as in screenshot even after reload. But in profile, hat returns to its position for a second before it goes back up!

Comment: And for every other user, hats stay where it should be staying!

Comment: Odd. Are you running any user scripts?

Comment: @DanielFischer, no, greasemonkey is disabled at the moment; I use NoScript, all but Quantserve and Scorecard are allowed on math.SE, even tried allowing scripts globally.

Comment: ...and in leaderboard; link to profile is clickable only on hat trying to fly away, not in the white box!

Comment: This should have been tagged [bug]; otherwise developers won't see it. Fortunately, the bug will be fixed in 4 hours anyway.

Comment: Since I log into Math.SE using Facebook, my profile pic is pulled from my Facebook page. Could that be what is causing problems? The only time my profile pic has ever failed to load for me is when Facebook is down, and I haven't seen that happen during Winter Bash.

Comment: @Normal fixed, and gone! :D

Comment: @JimmyK may be! I can't see your profile pic still, its empty and hat is helium filled in Leaderboard still!! Tagging as bug! Anyway, congrats, you finished second in math.SE in hatchase!

Comment: I highly suspect it's caused by something on client side. I tried to reproduce this bug , by blocking Jimmy's image source using ad block plus extension, and here is the [result](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TZXRx.png) same as picture you posted (I've done this in chrome 47/win 7)

Comment: @user2838619, true, I had forgotten those two little devils I hid from my toolbar (Disconnect.me/uBlock Origin) Disabling them all (even TiddlyFox Extension) made his floating hat disappear (again, only his hat); and show his user name in white space. May be my firefox hates facebook that badly that it cuts all links to it! ;-) Should keep this post here or delete?

Comment: I'm not sure about deleting or keeping the post, but I think the bug tag isn't relevant,according to tag wiki. Also there are some other users on the leader board that have their avatar picked from facebook(Tim B on worldbuilding for example), those this happens to them?

Comment: @user2838619, no, only for him! Its normal for everyone else!

Comment: There is a chance that someone else will experience this issue next year, so keeping this post here would be a good idea.

Comment: Yeah, I remember I had this bug on Android 5.1 using Chrome.

Comment: @nicael, did you have any adblockers anything else installed?

Comment: No, as I've said, it was on Android, i.e. on my phone Galaxy S5. No ad-blockers.

Comment: I had the same problem as nicael on my android. Whenever I scrolled the page in Chrome, the hats stayed where they were and the rest of the page moved where I wanted. If I left it alone for a few seconds, the hats suddenly moved to their appropriate positions. It never happened in Firefox though, the hats moved with the page perfectly.